Relationship between $\log(\kappa)$ and $\log(n)$, and round complexity
Consider a protocol $\Pi$ that is parameterized by security parameter $\kappa$ and that handles inputs of size $n$. Suppose that $\Pi$ runs in $\log n/\log \kappa$ rounds.
Is it correct/fair to say that $\Pi$ is a constant-round protocol?
On the one hand, it seems it must be true, since $n$ must be bounded by some polynomial in $\kappa$, such that $\Pi$ can run in polynomial time. Namely, $n(κ) = O(poly(\kappa)) = O(\kappa^c)$ for some constant $c$. Thus, $\log n = O(\log \kappa)$, and the numerator and denominator are related by a constant $c$.
On the other hand, it seems strange to claim that $\Pi$ runs within constant rounds, but to be unable to name a single constant that bounds the number of rounds. Namely, one must specify the growth-rate of $n$, and then we can specify a particular constant.
If it is not a constant-round protocol what would one say about the round complexity of $\Pi$? Again, formally, the round complexity seems to be $O(1)$ -- is this what one should say?

I wouldn’t classify this as a constant-round protocol because the number of rounds varies with $n$. Although $n$ is polynomial in $\kappa$, the number of rounds still depends on both $n$ and $\kappa$. In other words, as $n$ grows larger, so does the value $c$, hence the number of rounds is not a fixed constant.
For instance, consider the interactive protocol for the graph non-isomorphism problem. Regardless of the input size and the security parameter, the protocol consistently operates in 2 rounds.

In that case, what would you say about the round complexity of $\Pi$? If the claim is that it runs in $O(\log n / \log \kappa)$ rounds, then why can I not turn around and say that this quantity is $O(1)$?

I would say the round complexity of $\Pi$ is super-constant (similar to super-linear functions). We can't say it is $O(1)$ because $n$ is not equal to (or bounded by) a fixed polynomial in $\kappa$. We would want to say a protocol $\Pi$ is a constant round protocol if for all $n = poly(\kappa)$, the number of rounds is a fixed constant. This is not the case in $\log(n)/\log(\kappa)$.

If the round complexity is super-constant, this means it is $\omega(1)$ right? In this case we have $\log n / \log \kappa = \omega(1)$. But this means $n = \kappa^{\omega(1)}$, which is super-polynomial, which does not make sense.
Or are you saying that it is incoherent to try to relate $n$ and $\kappa$ in the first place?

Yes, it is incoherent to try to related $n$ and $\kappa$ because in the definition, $n$ is not bounded by any fixed polynomial in $\kappa$. Recall, in the definition, it is for all $n=poly(\kappa)$, ...
